# Cannot get list of internal storage files

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a simple file explorer for my music player and I can't get access to an internal storage of my phone. I've tried `getFileDir()` - which return nothing and `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` crashes whole app, funny that only `Environment.getRootDirectory()` works fine but this is not what I need. I'm sending whole `File` objects to `RecyclerViewAdapter`, which works for `getRootDirectory` as I mentioned.

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private File mFile;
private ArrayList<File> mList = new ArrayList<File>();
private RecyclerView mRecycleView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayout;
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String path= getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
    mFile = new File(path);
    for(File file : mFile.listFiles()){
        mList.add(file);
    }

    mRecycleView = findViewById(R.id.RecycledView);
    mRecycleView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mLayout = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecycleView.setLayoutManager(mLayout);
    mAdapter = new RecycleViewAdapter(this,mList);
    mRecycleView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

My permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

I would be grateful for any advice.

Comment: "Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() crashes whole app" - which exception is being thrown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

Edit: I've just realised, adding the permission to the manifest isn't enough for Android 6+.
You need to request the permission at run time

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                1);
```

Comment: ive copied wrong text, getExternalStorageDirectory() crashes app, not getExternalStorageState() Sorry for that

Comment: Just updated my answer! Try requesting the permission at runtime

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, ive been trying to solve that for hours and now its working :D